# $C([0,1])$ with norm $\|f\| := \sum_{n=1}^\infty|\frac{f(q_n)}{2^n}|$ complete?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $(q_n)$ be a sequence of all rational numbers from $[0, 1]$. On $C([0,1])$ let's consider norm:

$$\|f\| := \sum_{n=1}^\infty|\frac{f(q_n)}{2^n}|$$

I want to check whether norm $\|f\|$ is complete.

**My work so far**

Let's take $(f_k) \subset C([0,1 ])$ Cauchy sequence. We want to prove or disaprove that $$\exists{f \in C([0, 1])}: \|f_k - f\|\rightarrow 0 $$

I wanted first to focus on more general problem:

$$\exists f: \|f_k - f\| \rightarrow 0$$

and after proving that, we can focus on showing that such $f$ has to be in $C([0, 1])$.

So - because $(f_k)$ is a Cauchy Sequence then:

$$\exists_l : \|f_k  - f_l\| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|f_k(q_n) - f_l(q_n)|}{2^n} \le \epsilon$$

for any $\epsilon > 0$

$$\|f_k  - f\| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|f_k(q_n) - f(q_n)|}{2^n}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|f_k(q_n) - f_l(q_n) + f_l(q_n) - f(q_n)|}{2^n} \le$$
$$\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|f_k(q_n) - f_l(q_n)|}{2^n} + \frac{|f_l(q_n) - f(q_n)|}{2^n} \le$$
$$\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} + \frac{\sup\{|f_l(q_n) - f(q_n)| : n \in \mathbb{N} \}}{2^n} = \epsilon + \sup\{|f_l(q_n) - f(q_n)| : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$.

And here I got stuck, because $\sup\{|f_l(q_n) - f(q_n)| : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is not arbitrary small. Do you know how to fix this/could you please give me a hint what is correct approach to this problem

Comment: Better is maybe to show the equivalence of your norm with the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. That $\|\cdot\|\leq C\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is easy, and for the converse, use that $\sup_{[0,1]}|f|=|f(x)|$ for some $x\in[0,1]$ by continuity of $|f|$ and by compactness of $[0,1]$, then use that rational numbers are dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Nicolas : Both norms are *not* equivalent. Take $N$ an integer and choose a function $f$ with values in $[0,1]$, with $f(q_n) = 0$ for $n\leq N$ and $f(q_{N+1}) = 1$. Then $\|f\|\leq 2^{-N}$ while $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$.

Comment: @SolubleFish Yes my bad: I was thinking to $\|f\|_\infty\leq\varepsilon+2^N\|f\|$ where $N$ is such that $|f(x)-f(q_N)|\leq\varepsilon$; but the constant $2^N$ is not universal indeed! By the way, in your answer, you shall rather take $1/\sqrt{2}$ as $x>\sqrt{2}$ is impossible for $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for the feedback. I edited my answer to take this into account

Answer (score 3):

Let $E$ be the space of functions $f:[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q\to\mathbb R$ such that $\|f\| < +\infty$. We can quite easily see that $E$ is complete and $C([0,1])$ is (isomorphic to) a subspace of $E$. But we will show that it is not complete.

For example, let :
$$f_k(x) = \tanh\big(k(x-1/\sqrt{2})\big)$$
Then, we have :
$$\forall x \in \mathbb Q\cap[0,1], \lim_{k\to +\infty} f_k(x) = f(x)$$
where $f(x) = 1$ for $x>1/\sqrt{2}$ and $f(x)=-1$ for $x<1/\sqrt{2}$. Since $|f_k(x)|\leq 1$, the dominated convergence theorem gives :
$$\|f_k - f\| \to 0$$

Therefore, $f_k \to f$ in $E$. Therefore, $(f_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $E$, and also in $(C([0,1],\|\cdot\|)$, but has no limit in $C([0,1])$